# value of formControl not displayed on view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a form with many fields, It was made with formGroup and formControlName.
The problem is when I start the app I need to get the data from the backEnd and display it on the view.

The problem is that the field Funcion is not displaying the value:

[image]

Here is a reduced part of my html code:

```
<form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="registros" class="fila-contenido">
                <div class="campos">
                    <!-- En Venta THIS IS OK-->
                    <label>¿En venta?</label>
                    <mat-radio-group formControlName="enVenta" aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label"
                        class="example-radio-group">
                        <mat-radio-button value="1" class="example-radio-button">Si</mat-radio-button>
                        <mat-radio-button value="0" class="example-radio-button">No</mat-radio-button>
                    </mat-radio-group>
                </div>

                <!-- Activo THIS IS OK-->
                <div class="campos">
                    <label>¿Registrado?</label>
                    <mat-radio-group formControlName="activo" aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label"
                        class="example-radio-group">
                        <mat-radio-button value="Si" class="example-radio-button">Si</mat-radio-button>
                        <mat-radio-button value="En Trámite" class="example-radio-button">En Trámite</mat-radio-button>
                        <mat-radio-button value="No Necesita" class="example-radio-button">No Necesita
                        </mat-radio-button>
                        <mat-radio-button value="No" class="example-radio-button">No</mat-radio-button>
                    </mat-radio-group>
                </div>

                <!-- Pais THIS IS OK-->
                <mat-form-field appearance="">
                    <mat-label>Pais</mat-label>
                    <mat-select formControlName="pais">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let pais of selectedPaises" [value]="pais">{{pais}}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>

                <!-- Funcion THIS IS NOT OK-->
                <mat-form-field appearance="">
                    <mat-label style=" font-weight: bold;">Función</mat-label>
                    <mat-select formControlName="funcion" required (selectionChange)=changeFuncion($event)>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let funcion of funciones" [value]="funcion">{{funcion.Funcion}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

And here is the TS code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.getRegistros();


  }

getRegistros() {
    this.http.get<Registro>('http://localhost:7000/api/registros/' + this.service.getRow()).subscribe(data => {
      data.log = data.log.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
      console.log("formateo", JSON.parse(data.log));
      let convert = JSON.parse(data.log);

      this.registros.controls.enVenta.setValue(convert.enVenta); //this is OK
      this.registros.controls.activo.setValue(convert.activo); //this is OK
      this.registros.controls.pais.setValue(convert.pais); //this is OK
      this.registros.controls.funcion.setValue(convert.funcion); //this is not OK

});
}
```

What I've tried:
I've a write a console.log with all the values of the form, the form has all values included the one that is not displayed.

I think it can be related to the ngOnInit problem. But I tried to put `getRegistros()` on `ngAfterViewInit` and I was having the same problem :(
Also I tried to use `patchValue()` instead of `setValue()` but same problem

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Please do not name your variables in Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Angular uses object identity to select option. It's possible for the
>   identities of items to change while the data does not. This can
>   happen, for example, if the items are produced from an RPC to the
>   server, and that RPC is re-run. Even if the data hasn't changed, the
>   second response will produce objects with different identities.

To overcome this issue we have to provide the compareFn function to mat-select using compareWith input that tells Angular how to compare the values.

**Try this:**

**component.html**

```
   <mat-form-field appearance="">
                <mat-label style=" font-weight: bold;">Función</mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="funcion" required (selectionChange)=changeFuncion($event) [compareWith]="compareWithFn">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let funcion of funciones" [value]="funcion">{{funcion.Funcion}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
```

**component.ts**

Here i am assuming your funciones object contains id property.

```
compareWithFn(listOfItems,selectedItem){
     return listOfItems && selectedItem && listOfItems.id === selectedItem.id; ;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Do I have to add the CompareWithFn to all formFields that are selects?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. You saved my life. I modified a bit the compareWithFn, with that code:
`compareWithFn(item1, item2) {
  return item1 && item2 ? item1.nom === item2.nom : item1 === item2;
}`

Comment: Glad to be of help 

Comment: When the value is an object, not a number, you always must implements a function compare. Java do that too.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in your template file:

Updated Template:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="">
                    <mat-label style=" font-weight: bold;">Función</mat-label>
                    <mat-select formControlName="funcion" required (selectionChange)=changeFuncion(funcion) [(ngModel)]="funcion">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let funcion of funciones" [value]="funcion">{{funcion.Funcion}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
```

Component:

```
funcion:any;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but adding ngModel to a form-field it is not recomended.
If you have a look at my html code, you can see that I have another "select" called "pais" and it has not ngModel and it's retrieving data.

Comment: yeah that should work without ngModel as well, may i know why you are using {{funcion.Funcion}} here ?

Comment: Hi, because the object has 2 different fields but I only need to display 1..

Comment: Ok, could you create a reproducible demo on stackblitz and you should not use #f="ngForm" if you are using reactiveForms approach.