# Why cant setValue() is not assign to formControlName?

Tags: angular

**I am not  able to set formcontroName of mat-stect using setValue() i**

**HTML**

```
            <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid">
                                        <mat-select  placeholder="Choose Manufacturer"  formControlName="prod_manfId">
                                        <mat-option  *ngFor="let item of listOfmanufacture" 
                                              value={{item.manf_name}}>{{item.manf_name}}</mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>

                                        <mat-error>
                                            Manufaturer is
                                            <strong>Required</strong>
                                        </mat-error>
                                        <!-- <mat-hint align="start">Please Enter 
                                            <strong>Country</strong>
                                        </mat-hint> -->
                                    </mat-form-field>
```

**TS FILE**

```
         addManufacturer()
            {
            this.dialog.open(ManufactureEditComponent,{
                 data:'',
                  width:'900px',
                height:'400px'
              }).afterClosed().subscribe( res =>{
               console.log("RES"+JSON.stringify(res));
               //RES[{"manf_name":"1213","manf_city":"","manf_id":51,"manf_zipcoe":"",
                 //"manf_contactNo":"0","manf_status":1,"manf_createdById":2,"manf_code":"21312",
                 //"manf_addr2":"","manf_place":"",
               // "manf_clinicId":1,"manf_addr1":"","manf_contactPerson":""}]

                 let name=res[0].manf_name;
              
                  this.resultDate=res[0];

                      this.productModel.prod_manfId=res[0].manf_id;

             let value=this.productForm.controls.prod_manfId.setValue(name);



            });
           }
```

**Anyone has any idea? i tried setValue() and patchValue() but both did not work , then i tried this way to setValue like this.productForm.controls['prod_manfId'].setValue(name)**

Comment: May be this will help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469699/value-of-formcontrol-not-displayed-on-view/62469988#62469988

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? What does your FormGroup look like ? Do you have a [formGroup] in your HTML ? if you dont, you can't use formControlName and have to use [formControl] instead.

Comment: there is no error and even the formGroup declared properly.

Comment: <form [formGroup]="productForm" class="m-form m-form--group-seperator-dashed">